# Is this series already known?

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

I have the series $\sum_{k=0}^{N} \binom{N}{k} x^{k} y^{k(k-1)/2}$. Is this a function that can be evaluated more easily than just performing the sum?

Some points: if $y=1$, we have the binomial expansion of $(1+x)^N$. As a bit surprisingly, in equation number $20$ of https://arxiv.org/pdf/1001.2903.pdf one can see that the right hand side is very similar to my series, but in my case, the binomial coefficient is the usual one, while in the equation number $20$, one has a $q$-binomial coefficient.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: A comment: with the Hubbard-Stratonovich transformation (see the second equation in http://www.colorado.edu/physics/phys7240/phys7240_fa14/homework/Problem_Set_2_sol.pdf) I could transform the quadratic term in $k$ into a sum (integral) of terms linear in $k$. As a consequence, the series in $k$ could be summed, but an integral would remain. Is this considered a good strategy to proceed?

Comment: This series is in fact a probability distribution (when normalized to 1), well known in physics. The "funny" thing is that for some special parameters $x$ and $y$, the probability distribution changes abruptly in shape, given small changes in the parameters. In the case of very large $N$, the change is almost discontinuous (strictly, only discontinuous in the infinite case). I would like to understand why for these parameters the behavior of the probability distribution is like this: sudden changes, and bi-modal distributions.